# Is there any automated testing tool for mobile applications written in Delphi?

Tags: android, ios, software-testing, delphi

I am developing an Android/iOS app using Delphi. I would like to know if there are affordable (for a single developer) test automation solutions available for apps written using Delphi 10.3.3. Tried some of the opensource offerings, but none was found to be having support for apps written using Delphi. Did try compiling the application with debug information to enable object identification. None of those was a success.